# Are Stormtroopers paid or rewarded in any way for their service?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, stormtroopers

First off, I have only seen [the seven episodic films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars#Saga_films) in the Star Wars franchise. I am aware of vast amounts of other canon and non-canon sources available. Much of the fun I have on this Stack Exchange site is reading the about some of these questions.

From reading here and following links to Wikipedia or [Wookieepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wookieepedia) I have seen that once the events of Episode I to III are completed, the Empire switched from clones to regular humans prior to the events of Episode IV. This system seems to be in place through Episode VI. When we get to Episode VII humans are still being used.

From what I understand from the troops in Episodes IV - VI the humans are recruited, conscripted, or volunteer for service in the Empire (hence Luke mentioning wanting to go to the Academy). This would mean they some (if not many) Stormtroopers have a family of sorts. However, by the events of Episode VII it seems that the [First Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Order_%28Star_Wars%29) is stealing/kidnapping (?) children to train them to be soldiers (Finn's comments on the matter suggest this).

So, to get to my question, I assume that clones (I-III) and kidnapped children (VII) would *probably not* need to be paid. The recruits/volunteers from Episodes IV-VI would be the *most likely* to be paid/rewarded. As we see with armies here on Earth, a soldier is paid even when drafted (formal armies like the US anyway). I would think there is something similar in place for the Empire or there would be no talk of an Academy or recruits, the Empire would just conscript their soldiers. **Do we see any instances of Stormtroopers being paid/rewarded for their service?**

Disney canon is preferred, but Legends are acceptable.

Comment: I imagine payment goes something like this: “I am altering the deal. Pray I don’t alter it any further.”

Comment: @amaretto This deal gets worse all the time.

Comment: @amaretto but there was still a deal...  and Vader allowed Lando to live. We also see Vader making concession to Boba a few scenes later.

Comment: the turks kidnapped children in the balkans and forced them to fight. they rose to ranks to command armies and got paid well.  What makes you think they would be treated any differently than other soldiers?

Comment: @hownowbrowncow Good point, I was just going on that the volunteers would be *most* likely to be paid. I am am going to edit the question slightly.

Comment: When Luke mentions going to the Academy, I don't take that to mean that he would enlist with the Empire, particularly considering that he is in the presence of the rebellion at the time and seems to know some of them quite well.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy it could ONLY mean that http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63497/what-academy-was-luke-trying-to-attend although, he planned on defecting to Rebellion as well...

Comment: Storm Trooper signing bonus: Free Range Access for life  (or until someone with a sword shoots you. Whichever comes first.)

Comment: Now *that* would explain why they apparently keep missing their targets despite being considered excellent marksmen. They shoot to miss!

Comment: They gotta get paid or there'd be a nasty revolt on their hands .It's like "let's see you force-choke all 10 million of us. "

Comment: @coburne (Referencing the statement in your quoted text.)  Bad idea.  Don't unnecessarily test the theory that there's a specific limit that you're thinking there might be.  The cost of guessing wrongly would be quite high.

Comment: They are probably paid in hookers--the Clone Whores.

Comment: @coburne that was my thought exactly!

Comment: @JohnSensebe do they look like Jango Fett?  If not, then no deal.

Comment: They were paid in the same way that Cthulhu's supporters are paid: Those who obey are eaten last.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the new (and canon) short story [Born in the Storm](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Born_in_the_Storm), Stormtroopers are indeed paid.

We learn that their pay is subject to sanction along with other disciplinary measures if they fail to complete incident forms correctly.

> And remember, **failure to comply with proper Imperial military protocol
>   can result in disciplinary action including docked pay**, loss of
>   equipment, expulsion, and/or summary execution. Remember also that
>   this is an official imperial document and any discrepancy between what
>   you write and what actually occurred is an infraction of the Imperial
>   military protocol. Thank you for your service!

Comment: That is written like it came from the game Paranoia!

Answer (score 66):

In the new canon book "Battlefront: Twilight Company" - we follow the story of a female volunteer Stormtrooper on Sullust named Thara Nyende.

In Chapter 3 we see:

> She'd joined with the intention of serving one tour of duty, making
>   more money than she possibly could elsewhere

We later see her distributing extra credits, supplies, and rations to her family and friends, so she appears to be receiving some manner of legitimate compensation

from Kindle version, page 121

Comment: Unless i'm wrong, Kindle's page numbers depend on your screen size. You'd be better off quoting the location instead.

Comment: You are sort of wrong @AayushAgrawal - newer books do include page numbers that are different from the relative location identifier (this also depends on the publisher I believe)  - http://www.macworld.com/article/1157919/kindle_app_real_pages.html

Answer (score 23):

Stormtroopers apparently have some kind of low-paying pension scheme:

[image: Dr. Aphra holding a device and saying, "The Imperial stormtrooper pension scheme isn't exactly market leading, Bossk. They're not letting anyone with anything other than a program in their head anywhere near the rich stuff. Get ready..."]

(*Darth Vader* #8, Disney canon)

Transcription:

> The Imperial stormtrooper pension scheme isn't exactly market leading, Bossk. They're not letting anyone with anything other than a program in their head anywhere near the rich stuff. Get ready...

Comment: Maybe include a transcription of the text for people whose computers can't load all images. The words are so tiny in the image. :)

Comment: And additionaly maybe note what this is exactly expressing?!

Comment: @Zaibis To be honest, I'm not completely sure whether I understand it myself. The panel is from the beginning of a comic where Dr. Aphra (the character pictured here) is trying to steal a bunch of Imperial loot, but I don't get how stormtroopers not making very much money when retired is related to the security around the loot.

Comment: @MiloPrice maybe that minimum wage guards are more likely to either pilfer the loot themselves, or run away when attacked. So they guard the good stuff with the better-paid elite guards?

Comment: Not just "elite guards" but those either robotic and following strict priorities without choice (literally programmed) or fervently loyal to the death (figuratively programmed). @gbjbaanb