# How are droids related to the harvest?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

From *A New Hope*:

> Luke: In fact, I, uh, was also thinking about our agreement—about me staying on another season? And if these new droids do work out, I want to transmit my application to the academy this year.
>
> Owen: You mean the next semester before the harvest?
>
> Luke: **Sure. There's more than enough droids**.
>
> Owen: Harvest is when I need you the most. It's only one season more. This year we'll make enough on the harvest that I'll be able to hire more hands and then you can go to the academy next year.

How are droids related to the harvest ?

Comment: They fix the 'vaporators which means the farm has moisture to sell.

Comment: So ancient. Just install Zoom! (I wonder what Luke intended to study? Or did he mean military academy?)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer In Legends, he meant an Imperial military academy; he was planning to go there, learn to fly properly, and then defect to the Rebellion, the way his friend Biggs did. I don't know if all this is still the case in canon.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer - ["What Academy was Luke trying to attend?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63497/what-academy-was-luke-trying-to-attend)

Comment: @Valorum There is an alternate history movie of Luke doing an Saeed Alshamrani manoeuver in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Droids are used to manage the moisture vaporators on which the farm depends for its existence. The Lars family make a reasonable living from the harvesting of atmospheric moisture which they sell to other local sub-surface hydroponic farmers (like Camie's parents), to the nearby settlements like Mos Eisley and which they use to grow their own crops to eat and sell.

The need for human/droid labour is greatest when their and others crops are close to harvest because a) the need for water is [at its greatest when the crops are closest to harvest](http://www.fao.org/3/s2022e/s2022e02.htm) which means that their vaporators need to be running at top efficiency to provide the much-needed water or risk suffering a catastrophic crop harvest failure and b) that the vaporators seem to particularly suffer from sand-clogging at harvest time due to the combination of continuous use, lubricants and (presumably) slightly-higher-than-average moisture in the air.

The [Official Star Wars Fact File #8](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_8) gives us a little more info about the need for droids and humans to service the towers, clean filters and communicate with the vaporators to ensure that they remain in good working order.

> MAINTENANCE:
> Exposed to the planet's
> frequent sandstorms,
> **vaporators can easily
> become clogged by sand
> particles attracted to the
> machine's sticky lubricants.**
> Maintenance droids ore
> commonly used to ease
> this unending routine.

and

> AN UNCERTAIN LIFE: Maintaining the vaporators
> is a prime concern for
> farmers, many of whom employ
> farmhands or droids to monitor and
> maintain their vaporators continually, as
> loss of water production can often lead
> to bankruptcy in such a precarious
> enterprise. **Using
> droids assists the
> smooth running of
> a moisture farm,
> particularly during
> the labour-intensive season prior to harvest.
> In addition to
> agricultural robots and maintenance
> droids, it is often necessary to utilize the
> more sophisticated robots needed to
> translate the binary programming
> language used by the vaporators.**

Comment: "labour-intensive season prior to harvest"  Heh.  Someone's getting carried away with the "farming" analogy.

Comment: @DavidW - The issue at hand is that the Lars do two kinds of farming. They 'farm' moisture from the air and they literally grow crops underground. The two are interrelated and they need to do more of the former when it's nearly time to harvest the actual crops.